# Flutter - How to rebuild/call Parent Class Build method from Child Class

Tags: flutter

To reduce code duplication and increase the runtime performance (avoid repeated rebuilding of big form - 16+ fields)_ I have extracted `DropdownSearch` widget to a separate `StatefulWidget` class.

In my child's (DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect) class I return the widget. In the widget their is `onChanged` method on which I set the field (string) from parent class which I have passed as an object to the constructor of child class. When I execute the setState method a rebuild is triggered for child (DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect) class.
I wish to trigger rebuild for parent class (ProcessStart Class). How do I achieve the same? I tried `super.stateState` and `super.build` but it didn't work.

The reason parent's (ProcessStart) class rebuild is to re-triggered is because the succeeding item is to be enabled only after data has been filled in all preceding items.

Child Code (DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect Class) :

```
class DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final String label;
  final Ref<String> itemSelected;
  final bool enabled;
  final Future<List<String>> Function(String?) retriveItemList;
  const DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect({
    required this.label,
    required this.url,
    required this.itemSelected,
    required this.enabled,
    required this.retriveItemList,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect> createState() =>
      _DropDownSearchSingleItemSelectState();
}

class _DropDownSearchSingleItemSelectState
    extends State<DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('In Child Widget : ${widget.itemSelected.ref}');
    return DropdownSearch<String>(
      ...
      enabled: widget.enabled,
      selectedItem: widget.itemSelected.ref,
      onFind: widget.retriveItemList,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(
          () {
            widget.itemSelected.ref = value ?? '';
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Parent Code (ProcessStart Class) :

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
    // * Product Code
    DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect(
      label: 'Product Code',
      itemSelected: _productCode,
      enabled: true,
      retriveItemList: productCodeDecodeJson,
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 10.0,
    ),
    //Batch Number
    DropDownSearchSingleItemSelect(
      label: 'Batch Number',
      itemSelected: _batchNumber,
      enabled: _productCode.ref.isNotEmpty ? true : false,
      retriveItemList: batchNumberDecodeJson,
    ),
    const SizedBox(
      height: 10.0,
    ),
    ...
)
```

Comment: I can't provide high quality answer, ask for your understanding in that. My idea is to pass callback calling `setState` of parent widget. Then child will be able to call or forward it.

Comment: @jeiea I created callback where I execute the `setState` method only.